# how receiving double-digit instead single-digit using $.each function

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

I've solved problem with receiving data from mysql, they will appear in the form( 23,34,65,67...etc),but appeared a new problem, by using a $.each() function, I receives only single-digit numbers like 2,3,3,4, instead 23,34...etc, how can i slice data on double-digit number using $.each() function??

```
$("#add").click(function()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax.php",
        data: "buttons="+ tab_of_button,
        success: function(){
            $('div.success').fadeIn();

            $.get("sendback.php",function(data)
            {

                 $.each(data, function(index, value)
                 {
                     alert(value);

                 });
            });
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

**sendback.php**

```
<?php

$ask = mysql_query("SELECT numbers FROM buttons");
if(!$ask)
{
    die('Incorrect ask'.mysql_error());
}
else{
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($ask)) 
    {

        $tab[] = $row['number'];
        foreach($tab as $buttons)
        {
            echo $buttons;

        }

    }
    mysql_free_result($ask);

}
?>
```

**html**

```
<html>
<body>
.
.
.
<ul id="_button">
<li id="01" >01</li>
<li id="02" >02</li>
<li id="03" >03</li>
<li id="04" >04</li>
<li id="05" >05</li>
<li id="06" >06</li>
.
.
.
<li id="40" >40</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should fix the output of your php file. If that gives you a string (of numbers), the only thing you can do on the client is parse each character individually, or the string as a whole.

This gives you a json array, so you can fetch each element on the client.

```
$tab = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($ask)) 
{

    $tab[] = $row['number'];
}
echo json_encode($tab);
```

Comment: For now its working, i received data as["23","34",....etc],but now must slice this data, i used $.getJSON function to get data and splite function to slice array in the loop $each function, by use alert i should get digit in sequence, but function display nothing, any solution?

Comment: Why would you need to slice the data? You can simply use `$.each(data, function(ix, value){alert(value)});` to loop over the items in data.

Comment: I use this slice data to disable button with specified ID(numbers from  data).`$("#_button li").eq((value)-1).css("background","grey");.
        $("#_button li").eq((value)-1).attr("disabled",true);.
        $("#_button li").eq((value)-1).unbind();`

Comment: You can simply use `$.each()` to achieve that. Just use your code instead of the alert in my previous comment. That will work ([see Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ELrxP/)), unless you have a more complex structure that is returned from the php function.

Comment: I thing that receive data are string,so, changed the data to number using parseInt, after I used $each function but get only first index of array, changed code is above, maybe i done something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not using the data returned from your ajax call as the parameter name is in quotes. You could trying changing this:

```
$('#_button').children().each(function() {
    $(this).find('data').css("background","grey");
    $(this).find('data').attr("disabled",true); 
});
```

to this:

```
$('#_button').children().each(function() {
    $(this).find(data).css("background","grey");
    $(this).find(data).attr("disabled",true); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I thing that receive data are string,so, changed the data to number using parseInt, after I used $each function but get only first index of array, changed code is below, maybe i done something wrong?

```
$.post('sendback.php', function(data) 
                    {

                  var arr;
                  var number;

                  arr = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                  $.each(arr, function(key, value) 
                 {

                     number = parseInt(value);
                     $("#_button li").eq((number)-1).css("background","grey");


                  });
                });
```